# Javascript Redirect Mobile Specific Page

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I have a website and a mobile version of that website and I want to use something to redirect users based upon their browser size.  At the moment I have:

```
<script>
if (screen.width <= 1024) window.location.replace("http://www.website.com/")
else window.location.replace("http://m.website.com/")
</script>
```

This works fine for redirecting to home pages but what about linking to specific pages based on external income sources? For example if someone reads my tweet about my latest blog which is at `http://www.website.com/post.php?id=1111`, how do I ensure that mobile users are redirected to `http://m.website.com/post.php?id=1111`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var reg = "www.website.com";
var mob = "m.website.com";

if(screen.width >= 1024) {
   if(window.location.hostname != reg)
      window.location.replace("http://" + reg + window.location.pathname + window.location.search)
}
else {
   if(window.location.hostname != mob)
      window.location.replace("http://" + mob + window.location.pathname + window.location.search)
}
```

Comment: Well this does redirect but it's redirecting me to the mobile version even when I'm at full size (1440)

Comment: @user3177012 Sorry, the if statement was backwards.

Comment: Thanks - I've added this new code but it's now constantly redirecting me and not loading

Comment: @user3177012 I thought that might happen. You need another `if` to check if the url is the same. I'll add it.

Comment: Well I've tried the new code and it's now not loading up the mobile vestion when I shrink the screen

Comment: That is correct. It is going off of the screen size, not the window size. If you want it to go off of the window, replace `screen.width` with `window.innerWidth`.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. Just for future reference take a look at these: [`Window`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) and [`Screen`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_screen.asp)